# Programmatically modify cron schedule in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I am writing a wrapper around the Github Issues API to allow managers in my company to set up daily reminder emails to be sent to their devs. I want this to be configurable through an admin console, and give them the flexibility of setting up reminders at any time of day and any number of times a day.

The main App Engine cron system is configured statically through the cron.yaml file and cannot be changed by user action. Looking at the documentation it appears like I can only do this by reimplementing an entire cron infrastructure on top of the basic App Engine cron. Am I missing something? Is there anything like this that is already available elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot setup programmatically the cron configuration.

You can configure a single cron which triggers a customized functions. This functions can read the configured crons (like datastore entities) and the launch different task based on your needs

Comment: Correct. just wanted to add that this has the disadvantage of having to have a cron with high frecuency will keep the instance forever awake consuming the free daily hours quota.